# Rounding the Double Values

Tags: java

## Rounding Issue

For Example

1. 598.59 ya 591.45 to be convert 600.
2. 541.0 to be convert 550.
3. 541.59 to be convert 550.

   ***Just check the last 2 digit ignore the
   decimal value. if last 2 digit in
   between 11- 19 it will converted 20 if
   21-29 then will converted 30 and so on..***

So What can i do for this.
Need ur Help.

thanks in advance....

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked through the standard Java API for a way to do this?

Comment: I don't really see a pattern here..

Comment: divide the number by 100, add 0.99, truncate. (if you like to round up to the NEXT 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[MathUtils](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/util/MathUtils.html)** [**[Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/)**] :
- `static double round(double x, int scale)` or
- `static double round(double x, int scale, int roundingMethod)`

```
MathUtils.round(598.59, -1); // 600.0
MathUtils.round(591.45, -1, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING); // 600.0
MathUtils.round(541.0, -1, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING); // 550.0
MathUtils.round(541.59, -1, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING); // 550.0
```

---

**For update in question**

> Just check the last 2 digit ignore the
>   decimal value. if last 2 digit in
>   between 11- 19 it will converted 20 if
>   21-29 then will converted 30 and so
>   on..

```
MathUtils.round((double) 111, -1, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP); // 120.0
MathUtils.round((double) 119, -1, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP); // 120.0
MathUtils.round((double) 121, -1, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP); // 130.0
MathUtils.round((double) 129, -1, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP); // 130.0
```

Cast to double to make sure `round(double x, ...)` is use, instead of `round(float x, ...)`.

Answer (score 4):

I am just guessing what you mean, but assuming you want to round to the nearest n you can do the following.

```
double d = Math.round(d / n) * n;
```

e.g. if n = 50

```
double d = Math.round(d / 50) * 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

okay, so you can use the Math class. like this:

```
Math.floor(myNumber); //541.59 -> 541, returns double
```

but in this case you have to define your "limit" for rounding. What's the purpose of this?

Comment: thanks dude... but i need different . like 541.59 instead of i use 544.0 ya 548.5689 now these will be converted 550.... just check the last 2 digits regarding last 2 digit it will convert.

Answer (score 1):

for example

```
public class RoundToTwodecimalPlaces {

    public static double roundTo2Places(double value) {
        assert value >= Long.MIN_VALUE / 100 && value <= Long.MAX_VALUE / 100;
        long digits = (long) (value < 0 ? value * 100 - 0.5 : value * 100 + 0.5);
        return (double) digits / 100;
    }

    private RoundToTwodecimalPlaces() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
598.59 ya 591.45 to be convert 600.
541.0 to be convert 550.
541.59 to be convert 550.
```

As for me :
    1.Divide by 10

```
59.859
54.10
54.159
```

2. Round to nearest not less integer and 3. multiply by 10. 
Received 
    600
    550
    550

Answer (score 0):

public class RoundToTwodecimalPlaces {

```
public static double roundTo2Places(double value) {
    assert value >= Long.MIN_VALUE / 100 && value <= Long.MAX_VALUE / 100;
    long digits = (long) (value < 0 ? value * 100 - 0.5 : value * 100 + 0.5);
    return (double) digits / 100;
}

private RoundToTwodecimalPlaces() {
}
```

}

Comment: This answer appears to duplicate this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516520/rounding-the-double-values/6516756#6516756).